# Reproducing table 3.3 from Elements of Statistical Learning

Tags: r, regression, self-study

I am trying to reproduce a table 3.3 in Elements of statistical learning. Specifically, I am trying to get the coefficient estimates for ridge regression and lasso. I know that the estimate can be a bit off depending on the seeding value, but I personally think it is significantly off. The code is below, and would appreciate if anyone can give me some help.

A link to data is here : http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/index.html

And a link to textbook is here : http://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/local.ftp/Springer/OLD/ESLII_print4.pdf

Relevant pages are page 61 and 63.

```
library(glmnet)
Prostate <- read.table("prostate.data", sep = "")
train <- Prostate[,10]
Y <- Prostate[,9]
X <- Prostate[, -c(9,10)]
X.scaled <- scale(X, TRUE, TRUE)

set.seed(1)
cv1 <- cv.glmnet(X.scaled[train,], Y[train], alpha = 0)
plot(cv1)
ridge.r <- glmnet(X.scaled[train,], Y[train], alpha = 0, lambda=cv1$lambda.min)
coef(ridge.r) 
                    s0
(Intercept)  2.467025897
lcavol       0.486393030
lweight      0.599533912
age         -0.014470377
lbph         0.137317539
svi          0.674949305
lcp         -0.110476104
gleason      0.019892200
pgg45        0.006930003

cv2 <- cv.glmnet(X.scaled[train,], Y[train], alpha = 1)
plot(cv2)
lasso.r <- glmnet(X.scaled[train,], Y[train], alpha = 1, lambda =cv2$lambda.min)
coef(lasso.r)
                      s0
(Intercept)  2.466987400
lcavol       0.556835090
lweight      0.605923475
age         -0.016916532
lbph         0.138909124
svi          0.700170345
lcp         -0.170851957   
gleason      .           
pgg45        0.008051421
```

The output table from the textbook is below.
[image]

Comment: What results did you get, and did you check how much they vary for different seed values? I don't think it makes sense to define lasso.r using the lambda from cv, which was defined using alpha=0. Also, there's no need to run glmnet again after cv.glmnet; you can get the coefficient estimates from the cv.glmnet object.

Comment: Note that your data are scaled **outside** of the CV process, so your training data contains information about your test data. More conventionally, one performs scaling inside of the CV.

Comment: So should I use cross validation before scaling? And then pick lambda from the cross validation and apply it to ridge regression on scaled covariates? Or do you mean, when I run cross validation, I should specify the function to standardize at the same time?

Comment: 1. Partition your data for CV. 2. Apply scaling to all data except fold $k$. 3. Fit model. 4. Using the center and scaling from (2), scale fold $k$. 5. Estimate performance.

Comment: So should I manually proceed all these steps? Is there any function which does everything?

Comment: Even if I did what you said, I still get different results.